# Redundant Sets of a map

Tags: ergodic-theory

I got the definition of redundant like:

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $T:X \rightarrow X$ a continuous map. Call a set $Y \subseteq X$ reundant for $T$ if $T(Y) \subseteq T(X \setminus Y)$.

Now I have to prove, that if $T$ has a redundant nonempty open set, then $T$ cannot be minimal. Is the converse true?

I think the converse is not true, for example the identity function on $[0,1]$ is a counterexample right?

Comment: What is "$T$ cannot be minimal" mean? Minimal with respect to what?

Comment: My definition of minimal is:  A subsystem of $(X,T)$ is any non-empty, closed, T-invariant set. A minimal set is a  subsystem which does not contain any other proper subsystem.

Comment: Your original statement is not true: consider $X:=\{0,1\}$ with discrete topology and the map $T$ on $X$ with $T(0):=1$ and $T(1):=0$.  Then $T$ is minimal but $Y:=\{0\}$ is a non-empty open redundant set.  Your counterexample for the converse is fine.

Comment: But $0$ is not redundant, is it? I mean $T(Y) = \{1\} $ but $T(X \setminus Y) = \{0\} $?

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry I misread your statement as $T(Y)\subseteq X\setminus Y$.